# React Native - componentWillReceiveProps to AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, asynchronous

I'm having a trouble with storing my data from "componentWillReceiveProps" to AsyncStorage, and I'm not even sure if it 's possible or not? Because I've already search the internet and there is no actually post about storing the "componentWillReceiveProps" datas to AsyncStorage.

So here's what I've got, the datas from my "componentWillReceiveProps" is basically from it's parent component/screen. And from here, when the user tap the send button the datas of my "componentWillReceiveProps" should be stored to AsyncStorage and then get it again once it is needed to show.

Here's my code

ModalScreen.js

```
export default class ModalScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: props.modalVisible,
            textQty: '',
            getDet: ''
            getID_Det: ''
            getPrice_Det: ''
        };
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            modalVisible: nextProps.modalVisible,
            OG_id: nextProps.id,                 // Data from other screen
            OG_price: nextProps.price            // this should be included in storing.
        })
    }

    setItem = () => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('Key_1', this.state.textQty, this.state.OG_id, this.state.OG_price);
        Alert.alert("Saved");
    };
    getItem = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('Key_1')
        .then((value) => this.setState({ getDet : value }))
        .then((value_1) => this.setState({ getID_Det : value_1 }))   // I'm not sure if this is the right way.
        .then((value_2) => this.setState({ getPrice_Det : value_2 }))
    }

        render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Modal
                animationType = 'slide'
                visible = { this.state.modalVisible }
                onRequestClose={() => { this.props.setModalVisible(false) }}>
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <Text>{this.state.OG_id}</Text>
                            <Text>{this.state.OG_price}</Text>
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.textInput}
                                placeholder="Enter Quantity!"
                                onChangeText = { data => this.setState({ textQty : data }) }
                                returnKeyLabel = "done"
                                returnKeyType = "done"
                            />
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress = { this.setItem }>
                                <Text>Send</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                             onPress = {() => { this.props.setModalVisible(false) }}>
                                <Text>Close</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <TouchableOpacity onPress = { this.getItem }>
                                <Text>Show</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <Text>{ this.state.getDet }</Text>
                            <Text>{ this.state.getID_Det }</Text>
                            <Text>{ this.state.getPrice_Det }</Text>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try it in componentDidMount lifcycle function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is actually good, but I solve it by creating other keys dedicated for the other items that I want to store in the AsyncStorage inside of a function.

Example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Det_id: [],
        Det_price: [],
        textQty: '',
        getDet: ''
    }
}

setItem = () => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('Key_1', this.state.textQty);

    AsyncStorage.setItem('Key_2',this.state.OG_id);

    AsyncStorage.setItem('Key_3',this.state.OG_price);

    Alert.alert("Saved");
};
getItem = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('Key_1')
    .then((value) => this.setState({ getDet : value }));

    AsyncStorage.getItem('Key_2')
    .then((value_1) => this.setState({ getID_Det : value_1 }));

    AsyncStorage.getItem('Key_3')
    .then((value_2) => this.setState({ getPrice_Det : value_2 }));
}
```

**NOTE:** Again I'm not sure if this is the right way but this is how I did it, if you guys happens to know a much better way to this feel free to share.